# How to open multiple Internet Explorer instances w/ different URL tabs for each instance via batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, internet-explorer, batch-file

What I'm attempting to do is create a bat file that auto loads every program that I use at work via normal startup. As of now, upon logging into my system I am able to run a desktop cleanup program, open up three different instances of Internet Explorer, and the few other dedicated programs I use on a daily basis. What I would love to be able to do would be the open individual tabs within those IE instances.

For example (these are random sites, not the ones I would use):

- Instance 1

  - www.google.com
  - www.yahoo.com
  - www.ebay.com
- Instance 2

  - www.nytimes.com
  - www.foxnews.com
  - www.wallstreetjournal.com
- Instance 3

  - www.fidelity.com
  - www.marketwatch.com

I'm assuming if this code was successfully created,
adding or removing instances/tabs would be easy.
As I'm talking about a work computer,
my access to administrator functions is limited.
I figured the best way to get this solved was to reach out to the pros! So what do you think? How can this be done?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?  How are you currently opening the three instances of IE?  Would a workaround be to reopen the previous session in each instance or do you need to specify the tabs?

Comment: Is it not sufficient to simply bookmark all these sites in 3 separate "folders". Then, from your "Favorites", you can select the folder and "open in tab group"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tab groups aren't a good enough solution, yeah, this is possible. What follows is a really crude batch script, but it should do the job (feel free to refine it):

```
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com
start http://www.yahoo.com
start http://www.ebay.com
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.nytimes.com
start http://www.foxnews.com
...
```

Basically, create new instances of IE for each window, then use ShellExecute (what CMD's `start` command does) to open additional sites as tabs in that window (**this assumes IE is the default browser and you have the option enabled to open URLs from external processes as new tabs in the current window**). Create new `iexplore` sessions as needed. The final and top session would, in your example, be the one with Fidelity and MarketWatch tabs.